# How can I summarize different times in table with the same ID?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make a table as in the picture, where we can write a person's name, their unique ID, date, what type of break they had and what time it was and after all it's recording difference between allowed and actual time.

So we have 3 types of break: Toilet break - 10 minutes, 1st break - 15 minutes, 2nd break - 30 minutes. If a person is late it is recorded into the table.

How can I summarize these difference minutes, for each unique ID?
You can do it manually if there's only 2 persons like on the picture, but if I have 100 unique ID's?

[image: [Example of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKuoj.png)]

| Name | Clock_number | Date | Type of break | Time out | Time in | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person1 | 123456 | 27/02/2024 | 1st break | 09:00 | 09:22 | 00:07 |
| Person2 | 789456 | 27/02/2024 | Toilet break | 09:00 | 09:20 | 00:10 |
| Person1 | 123456 | 27/02/2024 | 2nd break | 10:00 | 10:32 | 00:02 |
| Person2 | 789456 | 27/02/2024 | 1st break | 10:15 | 10:33 | 00:03 |
| Person3 | 555555 | 27/02/2024 | Toilet break | 08:15 | 08:33 | 00:08 |

I tried to use VBA, taking examples from other people questions, but as I'm newbie with it, it was showing me errors and I didn't know how to fix them. I've been trying different options I could find, but always had some issues, I attached pictures where I stopped.

This is where I stopped trying to fix it

[image: This is where I stopped trying to fix it]

This is error I get now

[image: This is error I get now]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, add example data easy to copy/paste with [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Also, add expected output example. And because you've tagged the question with `vba` add your code, what errors are you getting and what have you tried

Comment: Use `Get & Transform` (`Power Query`). Group by `ID` (or by `ID` and `Type of Break`) and aggregate by `SUM` for `Difference`. Or use a Pivot Table.

Comment: You could even use functions like `SUMIF` depending on what you wanted for an output.

Comment: Using `Power Query` will be more helpful here as suggested above ^^^ because it can easily quite a large amt of data.

Comment: What's your expected output?